# copy records in a master/detail clientdataset delphi dbexpress

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, dbexpress

How can I copy the information of a record from a master/detail clientdataset to a new record or to an existing one.

For example I want to copy te data of invoice No. 100 to Invoice No. 150 or the information of invoice No. 100 to a new Invoice

With IBX I did that with storedprocedures but I am running into trouble with clientdataset with 'lock conflict on no wait transaction' when I apply the updates, i think its becasue the information is already on the server side.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do it the way I think you're doing it. Two clientdatasets, CDS1 is source, CDS2 is destination then do CDS2.Insert, CDS2Field1.Value := CDS1Field1.Value etc, CDS2.Post, CDS2.ApplyUpdates.

The real question is why do you get that error, you need to provide more information to answer that, but if you google the error message you'll find lots of material explaining why it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Lock conflic on no wait transaction'?

AFAIR, it's an Interbase/Firebird error. It could mean that other connection modified the record and still doesn't committed yet....

UPDATE:
Other things that came to mind:

- Have you revised your DBX connection configuration? If you don't know/ignore what CommitRetaining is/do, make sure it's configured to FALSE. Otherwise, other problems will arise...
- On Firebird/Interbase, you can only commit/rollback from Client application. SPs have no business with transaction control.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Question, can I commit a storedprocedure?

Comment: I think that was it!! Thank you very very much
I put Commitretain =  false on params of the sqlconection and everything seems to work ok now, there is a lot to learn. 
Anything else I should put on that connection params to smooth things out?

Comment: From mind, no. But you can ease us in helping if you providing: RDBMS Name/Version/Edition (Examples: Firebird 2.1.1, Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, etc), IDE (delphi - you provided), IDE version (2010), and the library you're using (dbexpress - you provided).
If I doesn't knew the error message from mind and supposed you are Interbase/Firebird as backend this question would take much more time to get an answer.

Comment: And you are using what as backend: Firebird or Interbase?

Comment: It is Firebird 2.1 with dbexpress firebird driver from Chau Chee-Yang (http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/), delphi 2010 
Thanks a lot

Comment: You're using D2010, Professional Edition, right? ( I imagine, since if it was Enterprise you would use the official Fb driver)...